How can I convert a 2D rectangular grid to individual horizontal and vertical line segments wit GN?
I try to find a way to create a window frame like object procedurally with Geometry Nodes. The base object is a grid-mesh (we can assume, it is 2D, rectangular quad mesh, where every lines are orthogonal, but the spacing between individual lines can vary). There is an instance mesh, that I'd like to distribute across H and V edge loops. But I don't know, how can I find the edge loops in geom nodes, in the same way as with the ALT + click in edit mode on a line.
Here is an illustration, what I want to achieve:

A better example, where two separate objects are used as H and V lines:


I understand that you have a profile (defined as the "instance mesh") that you would like to put/instance along the vertical/horizontal edges of the grid. But I do not understand what are "edge loops". Do you mean a frame, i.e. a quadrilateral ? Or do you just want H/V crossing instances ?

Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Yes, the instances shoud cross each other. The ideal solution would be a setup, where separate objects can be used on horizontal and vertical lines, I edited the post to illustrate this.

did you try curve to mesh and mesh to curve?



update after changing the question:
Create a vertex group for the circle shaped lines, use this node group

result:

in the modifier use the vertex group as input:


Thanks your solution! It is quite close to my example visually, but not really solve my problem. I edited the post to better refine, what is my target. I want to use other objects as beams of the frame.

please try to not update your question for further "wishes" because the question should be clear. You can ask as many questions as you like here, but it is not recommended to change your question in that way that additional tasks will be added. Why not? first, it is a bit unfair for the person who answers. Second you can ask as many questions as you like - so just copy it and open a new one - maybe someone else likes the first answer. Thx for your understanding. Please click on the checkmark left of my answer if it helped. Thx.
